# DropDownList with SelectedIndex=0

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, drop-down-menu

I write a simple program, which connects with database and reads data from two tables and writes them into two DropDownLists (DDL). DDL has structure like parent and child. This is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FillControls();
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ddl_SelectedIndexChanged((DropDownList)PlaceHolder1.FindControl("ddlTurCountry"), null);
    }
    else
    {
        if (((DropDownList)PlaceHolder1.FindControl("ddlTurCountry")).SelectedIndex == 0) ddl_SelectedIndexChanged((DropDownList)PlaceHolder1.FindControl("ddlTurCountry"), null); //without this string dropDownList doesn't call ddl_SelectedIndexChanged() when it's SelectedIndex=0
    }
}

private void FillControls()
{
    Panel panel = new Panel();
    Label lbl = new Label();
    lbl.Text = "Country: ";
    panel.Controls.Add(lbl);
    DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
    ddl.ID = "ddlTurCountry";
    ddl.DataTextField = "CountryName";
    ddl.DataValueField = "CountryName";
    ddl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddl_SelectedIndexChanged);
    ddl.AutoPostBack = true;
    panel.Controls.Add(ddl);
    panel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));

    lbl = new Label();
    lbl.Text = "Kurort: ";
    panel.Controls.Add(lbl);
    ddl = new DropDownList();
    ddl.ID = "ddlTurKurort";
    ddl.DataTextField = "KurortName";
    ddl.DataValueField = "KurortName";            
    panel.Controls.Add(ddl);
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(panel);

    FillDDL("ddlTurCountry", "SELECT CountryName from Countries");
}

private void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (((DropDownList)sender).ID == "ddlTurCountry")
    {
        FillDDL("ddlTurKurort", "SELECT Kurorts.KurortName FROM Kurorts INNER JOIN Countries ON Countries.idCountry = Kurorts.idCountry WHERE (Countries.CountryName = N'" + ((DropDownList)PlaceHolder1.FindControl("ddlTurCountry")).SelectedValue + "')");
    }
}

private void FillDDL(string ddlID, string SQLCommand)
{
    ((DropDownList)PlaceHolder1.FindControl(ddlID)).DataSource = GetDataFromDB(SQLCommand);
    ((DropDownList)PlaceHolder1.FindControl(ddlID)).DataBind();
}

private DataTable GetDataFromDB(string SQLCommand)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string sqlcnString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=turs;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False";
    SqlConnection sqlcn = new SqlConnection(sqlcnString);
    if (sqlcn.State.ToString() == "Closed") sqlcn.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SQLCommand, sqlcn);
    dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
    sqlcn.Close();
    return dt;
}
```

This code doesn't work correct. When I run this program it starts well and two DDL fill with data. Then I begin to change Value in first DDL and it aslo works, but it works only if I don't choose the first Value.

If I choose the first value the second DDL doesn't fill. When I watch with debugger I see that the method `ddl_SelectedIndexChanged` doesn't apply when SelectedIndex of first DDL equal zero. In this case I added this line:

```
if (((DropDownList)PlaceHolder1.FindControl("ddlTurCountry")).SelectedIndex == 0) 
    ddl_SelectedIndexChanged((DropDownList)PlaceHolder1.FindControl("ddlTurCountry"), null);
```

into `Page_Load`, but I don't like this, and I don't understand why it doesn't work when `selectedIndex=0`.

**SOLVED**

```
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FillControls();
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack) ddl_SelectedIndexChanged((DropDownList)PlaceHolder1.FindControl("ddlTurCountry"), null);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're populating the drop down list every time your page refreshes.  Don't do that.
Only call FillControls() if !Page.Postback

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        FillControls();   
        //Not sure why you have this here, probably not needed
        ddl_SelectedIndexChanged((DropDownList)PlaceHolder1.FindControl("ddlTurCountry"), null);
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: everything disapper after postback, because oll controls creates dynamically

Comment: Why does the dropdownlist need to be dynamically created?  Can't you place it on your aspx page?

Comment: You can also look at this: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Creating-Dynamic-DropDownList-Controls-in-ASP.Net.aspx